# ImageButton size strange issue

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have a `LinearLayout` which contains a set of buttons: first one is a simple `ImageButton` and others are ImageButton subclasses which only contain some custom logic (presentation is not overidden). All images have the same sizes (`50dp`), but the first one is drawn larger than it is. Did someone face such trouble?

**PS:** this layout is also used for tablets and everything is ok there. I really disappointed.

**UPD:** I'll leave it here for the case if someone else will face such troubles. I made a silly typo in a drawable name. Be careful with the filenames.

[Layout code](http://pastebin.com/RiRdqZ3k)

[image]

Comment: i think in your project you placed different image size in drawable,drawable-ldpi folder. so it will take from that folder please create drawable folder and then paste your images and check it out.

Comment: WHen I've had that problem I had a misnamed file in one of the drawables folders.

Comment: @HalR, please, create an answer with you advice and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've had that problem, I had a misnamed file in one of the drawables folders.